# PHP How do I properly check if an array is multi-dimensional - strange array behavior

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

If I have this array:

```
$foo[0] = 'bar';
$foo[1] = 'bar bar';

echo $foo[0][1];

// result
a
// i.e the second letter of 'bar'
```

I want to check that $foo[0][1] is not set i.e if I had:

```
$foo[0][1] = 'bar';
```

it would evaluate to true, but in my original example of  $foo[0] = 'bar' I would expect that:

```
isset($foo[0][1])
```

would return false;

What's the correct way to test that please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP doesn't have multidimensional arrays. It has arrays of arrays. It's important to understand the difference.

You need to do:

```
if (is_array($foo[0]) && isset($foo[0][1])) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*doh*

it's ->

```
array_key_exists($foo[0][1]);
```

I'm still confused as to why PHP thinks the $foo[0][1] is set though...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_array($foo[0]));
```

and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr for reference on returning "a";

Answer (score 0):

By using $foo[0][1], you are actually accessing the first character of the string $foo[0].